# Does the Music app still exist for iphones?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music

I'm trying to get my iPhone 12 (running iOS 15) to play music (originally from CDs, not locked to any Apple account) that I synced using iTunes from an older mac. I've seen instructions referring to the (built-in) Music (not Apple Music) app, but the iPhone doesn't have this app installed, I can't find it on the store, and I don't want to subscribe to Apple's service (Apple Music) just to play my own mp3 files on my own phone.

Is this app still possible to find somewhere? Has it been quietly replaced by Apple Music? Is there an official way to play local files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to Offline/Synced music in the Music app on iOS though it does default to displaying Apple Music content. In the row of icons at the bottom of the Music app, one option should be "Library". This is where you will find any local/synced music.

Comment: Is the Apple Music app different from the Music app? If so, where can I find the latter?

Comment: @JacobSchwartz No, it is the same app.